# Unable to select form with querySelector

Tags: javascript, html, queryselector

I'm trying to select a form element in javascript using the querySelector but it won't work and sometime it returns the form element.

Here's my code:

#### JavaScript

```
const ele = document.querySelector('form');
console.log(ele);
ele.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    console.log("in the eventlister function");
    const pass = document.getElementsByClassName("P")[0].value;
    const cpass = document.getElementsByClassName("CP")[0].value; 
    const messagePara =document.getElementById("generated_message");
    if(pass != cpass){
        e.preventDefault();
        messagePara.textContent ="check your password!!";
                            messagePara.style.color= 'red';
                            return false;
    }
    else{
        messagePara.textContent ="";
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
 <form class="inputF">
                <div class="inputD">
                    <label for="fname" >Full Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fname" required>
                </div>
                <div class="inputD">
                    <label for="uname">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="uname">
                </div>
                <div class="inputD">
                    <label>Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" id="Email" placeholder="example@gmail.com" required >    
                </div>
                <div class="inputD">
                <label for="phn">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="number" id="phn">
                </div>
                <div class="inputD">
                    <label for="pass">Password</label>
                    <div class="pass">
                        <input type="password"  class="P IptP" required>
                        <i class="fa fa-eye-slash show-hide"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="inputD">
                    <label for="cpass">Confirm Password</label>
                    <div class="pass">
                        <input type="password"  class="CP IptP" required>
                        <i class="fa fa-eye-slash show-hide"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <div>
                    <button id="save_btn" >Continue</button>
                   </div> 
                </form>
```

I tried adding class for the form and select the form using the ClassName but still the same problem occurred. How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: The most likely cause is that the code is calling querySelector before the page has finished loading.  And the form doesn't exist.  Try moving the script to the end of the page so that it loads after the form.  Also check the developer console (press F12) for error messages.

Comment: Also, what about giving the form a unique id? This is a better thing to do anyways. Like this: `<form id="myForm">` and `document.querySelector('#myForm')`.

Comment: Also #2: Do you have other forms on the page, perhaps coming from a 3rd-party plugin? The `querySelector` may be getting that first if it occurs higher-up on the page. Yet another reason to use a unique id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When manipulating the DOM with a `<script>` in the `<header>`, you'll want to wait until the document has loaded.

```js
document.body.addEventListener('load',function(){
  // Your DOM sensitive code here
});
```

otherwise, you might want to include your script after the form tag

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- Your header; moving your script from here -->
<body>
<!-- Your form here -->
<!-- Move script here-->
<script>
// DOM sensitive code here as the last element in the body
</script>
</body>
```